# Can't pass object from angular service to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm using the service to $http.get my object and then pass it to my controller.

When I load the webpage and use F12 developer tools - the custom service(getService) is working fine to get the data object and store it in the responseObj.Announcement variable. I can use Chrome to look at the scope and see my object. **I'm unable to pass that object to my controller**

- *Is there an issue with one of my methods in either the service or the controller?*

I've been up and down stackOverflow looking for similar situations but I'm stumped.

**getService**

```
    class getService {
         static $inject = ["$http", "$window"]
         baseUrl: string = ConfigB.BaseAPIUrl;


         urlObject = {
             Announcement:  "Announcement",
         };

         responseObj = {
             Announcement :[],

         };

         constructor(
             public $http: any,
             private $window: any
         ) { }



         // method utilizing generic promise object for announcements controller
         public getAnnouncements()
         {
             this.getRequest(this.baseUrl + this.urlObject.Announcement, "Announcement");

         }

         public passData()
         { 
             return this.responseObj.Announcement;
         }


         //Generic angular $http promise object
         private getRequest(url: string, responseType:string)
         {


             this.$http.get(url)
                 .then((response) =>
                 {
                     this.responseObj[responseType] = response.data;

                 },
                 function (data) {
                     this.$window.alert("Error: " + data);
                 });   
         }
    }
    angular.module('App').service("getService", getService);
```

```
**My Controller:**

<pre><code>

class announcementController {
    static $inject = ["$rootScope", "$scope", "$window", "getService" ];

    Announcement: any = [
        { Message: "test" }
    ];
    constructor(
        public $rootScope: any,
        public $scope: any,
        private $window: any,
        private getService: any)
    {

    }

    public getAnnouncements() {

        this.getService.getAnnouncements()


    }

    public setAnnouncements() {
        this.Announcement = this.getService.passData();
    }

    init() {
        this.getAnnouncements();
        this.setAnnouncements();
    }       
}
angular.module('App').controller("announcementController", announcementController);
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're waiting for getRequest() to finish before running getService.passData().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the $http promise to resolve before running `setAnnouncements()`. You can do this by passing on the promise that $http will return, and then retrieving your data from the controller once it's finished.

In your service:

```
public getAnnouncements()
{
    return this.getRequest(this.baseUrl + this.urlObject.Announcement, "Announcement");
}

private getRequest(url: string, responseType:string)
{
    return this.$http.get(url)
    ...
```

In the controller:

```
public getAnnouncements() {
    return this.getService.getAnnouncements();
}

init() {
    this.getAnnouncements().then(() => {
        this.setAnnouncements();
    });
}
```

[Example JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jigamujaki/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: James you resolved my problem and taught me more about promises.  Thank you so much!